# Metrics Plugin issue in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have installed Metrics Plguin 1.3.8 in eclipse 3.7 indigo.After intalling and giving my system a restart I cant see any Metrics option in Project properties.

Any one have any idea on this.

Comment: What does the Eclipse Error View mentions? Metrics2 (http://metrics2.sourceforge.net/) is for Eclipse3.5 or 3.6, not sure about 3.7 though.

Comment: There is no error coming in logcat.EVen I have installed Metrics 1.3.6.I got the same problem. I have gone through source forge(http://sourceforge.net/projects/metrics2/forums/forum/1024529/topic/3465556) for error but unluckly there is no soluation for this.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem with Eclipse Juno and metrics 1 (1.3.6) .

After a few Eclipse upgrade and theming, the metrics doesn't work anymore. It was just showing the calculation progression but it doesn't display the calculation results anymore.

After some net search, i found that http://metrics.sourceforge.net/ evolve into http://metrics2.sourceforge.net/, so i make the change. But, the metrics 2 (1.3.8) shows the same problem.

After a little search in my Eclipse workspace files, i found a directory named ".metadata". Then a sub directory named ".plugins". Then a sub directory named "net.sourceforge.metrics" with two files inside :

- metricsdb.db
- metricsdb.lg

So, after quitting Eclipse, i go to "MyJunoWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/net.sourceforge.metrics/" directory, then i move the two files to another place, relaunch Eclipse, make a clean/full rebuild of my project from the package view. The metrics calculation results are now redisplayed. The dependency graph is also redisplayed.

The first step of version switching (metrics 1 to 2), result from my tests, and couldn't be necessary in all cases. Try first to move the two files.

Comment: I have the same problem. Tried to remove metricsdb.db and .lg files did not work for me :-(

Comment: I am using "Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0) Build id: 20181214-0600",  for some reason, I don't find a "net.sourceforge.metrics" under myWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/ directory, however, I after updated to metrics2, the problem solved.

Answer (score 12):

When you right-click the project to open its properties, make sure you are in the **Package Explorer** view.  It doesn't work if you are in Project Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

**To show up the Metrics window:**

1) Click on 'Window' in the top options bar.

2) Select 'Show View' -> 'Other' -> 'Metrics' -> 'Metrics View'.

**To Enable Project Metrics:**

1) Right click on project.

2) Select 'Properties'.

3) Click on 'Metrics' label.

4) Check the 'Enable Metrics'.

**You should be in the Package Explorer view.**

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Java Project in your Project Explorer. Then go to "Configure > Convert to Plug-in Projects", then click Finish in the dialog box.

Now again right click on the Java Project in your Project Explorer. Now go to "Preferences", you'll find "Metrics" in the left-hand side panel. Click on it and select "Enable Metrics". Now the Metrics view will show the computed metrics.

I'm using Eclipse Juno and Metrics 1.3.8.

Answer (score 0):

I know that I sounds like reviving the dead but I had a similar issue when upgrading from Indigo to Mars.

The plugin installed properly and everything but I couldn't configure or use it. I looked at the web and couldn't find anything until I remember that the first step is ALWAYS looking at the log (.metadata/.log). And this is what appear:

!MESSAGE Plug-in at '.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/plugins/com.stateofflow.eclipse.metrics_3.14.1.201104282140' does not have an OSGi bundle manifest. To use a 2.0 style plug-in you must install the plug-in converter service. Go to Help > Install New Software and install 'Eclipse 2.0 Style Plugin Support' from 'The Eclipse Project Updates' software site.

I the installed the Eclipse 2.0 Style Plugin Support and reinstalled metrics et voila! Everything back to normal.

Hope this helps as I ended here while troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I had a method declared twice in my unit test. This Error was hardly noticeable, since my Coverage was showing results.

Anyway, the ERROR in my Code was the reason I didn't see any more updates from the Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, metrics was not enabled.
so
1.) right click on the project in package explorer
2.) click on properties
3.) select metric
4.) enable the metrics
5.) click on apply and close

thats it ..